# How to make this quicker?

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script that uses SSH to log into servers on a text document, or what ever you choose the script to use, and executes a set command.

This script takes too long to go through a list of, say, 70, and sometimes it will also just randomly stop. It says it's still executing the script, but it stops sending commands.

I need a way to prevent it freezing, and also to make run much more quickly

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::SSH2;

open(fh,'<','servers.txt');
@newarray;
while (<fh>){
@array = split(':',$_);
push(@newarray,@array);
}

$a=0;
$b=1;
$c=2;
while ($c <= scalar(@newarray)){
    $ssh = Net::SSH2->new();
    if ($ssh->connect($newarray[$c])) {
        if ($ssh->auth_password($newarray[$a],$newarray[$b])) {
            $channel = $ssh->channel();
            $channel->exec('cd /tmp && perl p.pl');
            $channel->close;
            print "Command sent to --> ".$newarray[$c]."\n";
            } else {
                print "Could not authenticate to host $newarray[$c]\n";
                }
            } else {
                print "Could not connect to host $newarray[$c]\n";
            }
                $a += 3;
                $b += 3;
                $c += 3;
    }
```

Comment: We haven't seen your script.

Comment: the code is to long to comment, you can see the code at http://pastebin.com/wcsAaiM2

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wcsAaiM2 the code is there

Comment: Not even a shred of effort originally and we had to push to get code out you. Please give an indication of what you've tried and why it's failing. We're not here to do your work for you

Comment: I wouldn't know what to change in the code, I don't really know what to try, the code can be seen here http://pastebin.com/wcsAaiM2

Comment: Yes thank you, the first two times you posted the link it was obvious where the code was. You don't need to keep reminding us as if we're your private development team. Update the question to include specifics of what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried, benchmarks and stats, why you think it's failing or where the bottlenecks are. A little effort.

Comment: And how do you know the server isn't the problem? Perhaps there's a few rouge processes or tasks.

Comment: Ok I apologize for my ignorance, but can you help me?

Comment: You forgot to `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: You will get better results posting this question on [codereview.se] - StackOverflow is more for functional problems, and your code does work.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily parallelize the tasks with [ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.5/ForkManager.pm)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::SSH2;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

#######################
# Written by Iyzan    #
#######################

open(fh,'<','servers.txt');
@newarray;
while (<fh>){
@array = split(':',$_);
push(@newarray,@array);
}

# make 10 workers
my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager(10); 

for (my $i=0; $i < scalar(@newarray); $i+=3) {
        # fork a worker
        $pm->start and next;

        $a = $i;
        $b = $i+1;
        $c = $i+2;

        $ssh = Net::SSH2->new();
        if ($ssh->connect($newarray[$c])) {
                if ($ssh->auth_password($newarray[$a],$newarray[$b])) {
                        $channel = $ssh->channel();
                        $channel->exec('cd /tmp && perl p.pl');
                        $channel->close;
                        print "Command sent to --> ".$newarray[$c]."\n";
                } else {
                        print "Could not authenticate to host $newarray[$c]\n";
                }
        } else {
                print "Could not connect to host $newarray[$c]\n";
        }

        # exit worker
        $pm->finish;
}

$pm->wait_all_children;
```

Comment: ok so the problem with this script is that instead of executing the commands on all the servers, it only executes it on the first server multiple times in the list, so for example say the list goes "admin:admin:1.1.1.1 admin:admin:2.2.2.2" The script is supposed to execute the command on both of the servers and say Command sent to --> 1.1.1.1 and Command sent to --> 2.2.2.2, but instead it only says   Command sent to --> 1.1.1.1 over and over again.

Comment: @user3678068: This isn't going to work because instead of just sending the command to all of the servers once, all ten threads are doing the same thing. They each have their own private copy of `@newarray` (great choice of identifier, that) and all you have done is multiply the work to be done ten-fold. You need to pass parameters to the threads from the main process to tell each if them what they should be doing

Comment: @Borodin, thanks for finding the error. it has been corrected.